# How do I use the date_list from Generic Date Views in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-generic-views

I have this function I was using to convert date objects from my blog posts into a dictionary of years and months I can display in a sidebar:

```
def post_dates(self):
    """Get dictionary of dates for all posts."""
    grouped_dates = groupby(Post.objects.datetimes('published', 'month'),
                            lambda date: date.year)

    def get_months(dates):
        return [{'name': months[d.month],
                 'num':str(d.month).zfill(2)} for d in dates]

    dates = [{"year": year, 'months': get_months(dates)}
             for year, dates in grouped_dates]
    return dates
```

Now I'm moving to use [Generic Date Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/) all of which provide `date_list` on the context.

Currently a url for me looks like this:

```
 url(r'posts/(?P<year>\d{4})/?',
    YearArchiveView.as_view(model=Post, date_field="published"), name="post_year_archive"),
```

So I've not subclassed the view.

I *really* don't want to have to write a view for each. I thought you could do this in a `context_processor` but I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850735/django-context-processors-is-it-possible-to-access-current-context-in-contextpr)  you can't access current context from a contect processor.

How can I tweak my code to work for the Generic Date View without subclassing? If not let me know, and why?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You can't access the context where? What output are you looking for? Where are you hoping to use this code?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm looking to turn a list of `datetime` objects into a list of years dicts with months dicts in them. The code currently does that but I don't know how to apply it to the `date_list` on the view context.

Comment: Seems like a template tag would be the way to go.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I blame the heat for not thinking of that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman do you mean a filter?